# Usage of virtual functions when initializing a derived class

Tags: c++

Here is the code example I will base my question on:

```
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        A(char *t) {
            cout << "A: " << t << endl;
        }
        virtual void printInfo() {}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(char *t, char *tt) : A(t) {
            cout << "B: " << tt << endl;
        }
        virtual void printInfo() {
            cout << "B class";
        }
};

class C : public B {
    public:
        C(char *t, char *tt, char *ttt) : B(t, tt) {
            cout << "C: " << ttt << endl;
        }
        virtual void printInfo() {
            cout << "C class";
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    C c("Hello", "to", "you");

    A *a = &c;
    a->printInfo();

    //This program prints:
    //A: Hello
    //B: to
    //C: you
    //C class

    return 0;
}
```

Considering that my C class constructor initializes B, and B does A, how would I go about calling the virtual function in the B class? Or is this just a completely wrong approach?

Comment: Unfortunately, calling virtual functions in constructors and destructors doesn't work the way you'd expect.

Comment: Where do you want to add this call, and what expected output would you hope you would get?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You never said...

Comment: @cppguy There aren't any calls of virtual methods in constructor/destructor. Did you read the question actually?

Comment: @cppguy: On the contrary; it is perfectly intuitive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Did _you_? The title says "usage of virtual functions when initializing a derived class".

Comment: BTW stop binding string literals to `char*`. Use `char const*` or `std::string`. Doesn't your compiler warn you about this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For the record: _'how would I go about calling the virtual function in the B class?'_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nonsense... what's wrong with `a->B::printInfo()`? Unfortunately until the OP answers mine and aschepler's initial comments, we have no way of knowing what he's actually trying to do.

Comment: @aschepler I want to add this call in `main()` but I get kind of confused because when I added ` C c("Hello", "to", "you");` all the constructors in all the classes is initialized, which means I cant just write `B b` or something like that? That would mean 2 constructors for B?

Comment: @Lightness You'd need to `static_cast` `a` to `B*` (or `C*`) but I have a feeling that's exactly what the OP is looking for. Edit: Never mind, after reading the latest comment, this seems to have nothing to do with virtual functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes the compiler warned me about that, and I have already changed it.

Comment: Your question is still patently unclear. Perhaps some "desired output" would help? "I get kind of confused" is not a good question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Through `a` you can only get to `A::printInfo()` (because `a` is a pointer of type `A*`) and `C::printInfo()` (because the dynamic object is of type `C`).  You **can't** get to `B::printInfo()`

Comment: @Nilzone- You can't write `B b;` because `B` doesn't have a default constructor. What does this have to do with virtual functions? `struct foo{ foo(int) {} };`. You can't write `foo f;` for that either.

Comment: @PaulEvans: Sure you can; you just need a cast like Praetorian says (`a->B::printInfo()` indeed is insufficient). The middle layer of inheritance doesn't just magically disappear into the ether, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, but you never mentioned dynamic casting, you said `a->B::printInfo()`

Comment: @PaulEvans: Read my _whole_ comment. Not just selected parts of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm doing a bad job explaining - sorry about that. What I want to know is: You see in my code example how I declared an instance of C and had my base class pointing to it before calling the virtual function. How would I go about doing the same thing for B when the instance of the C class already have initialized the B constructor?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you mean your *other*, *later* comment... but you can't even use dybnamic casting to get to `B::printInfo()`, you could only get there from `a` by forcing the compiler to use it as a `B*` at compile-time -- which you can do for **any* pointer (or object)

Comment: @PaulEvans: Yes.... what is the problem?

Comment: @Nilzone-: It sounds like you have some confusion about how this stuff works, and it's resulting in your question making no sense (as far as I can tell). What is this "the instance of the C class already have initialized the B constructor" malarky? What is the relevance of initialisation? Why do you think it is important/a problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how do you propose to get to `B::printInfo()` from `a`?

Comment: @PaulEvans: Read Praetorian's comment, and my answer below. I don't know how to make it any simpler for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I mentioned being confused on this. I thought it was relevant because in order to be able to have the base class point to B, it needs to be initialized.

Comment: @Nilzone-: I still don't follow you. "have the base class point to B" makes no sense (no class "points to" anything), and your object (`c`) _is_ initialized: that's what the constructor call is doing, long before you form any base-class pointers or call `printInfo`. Which book are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm obviously not getting through to you, but that's mostly my fault due to bad explaining on my part. I'll think of a different design. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Nilzone-: I'm trying to understand so that I can find out where your misunderstanding is and give you that "eureka" moment where everything falls into place, but if you'd rather just give up and walk away then that's up to you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not at all. I'll give it one more shot: In `main()` I call the `c` constructor that, in return call `b`'s constructor and it calls `a` at last. Then I create a pointer of my base class, and let it point to `c` in order to call the virtual function. I want to know how I would go about doing that for B, considering that the C class' constructor have already called B's constructor, meaning it would be pointless to write something like this in main: `B b("Test", "test")` since it's already been done by C.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Again I'm sorry if the terminology is way off, and if what I'm writing doesn't really make sense, but I really want to understand.

Comment: @Nilzone-: No need to apologise. Right. Well that would also be declaring an entirely different object. Yes, your object `c` has been constructed and that means all three of its subobjects (the `C` inside, the `B` inside and the `A` inside) are all "initialised". That's done and dusted, no need to think of it any more. After that, take a pointer to `c` however you like; such a pointer can safely be a `A*`, a `B*` or a `C*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm pretty my bad design leads to over complicating not so difficult things, but there is no easy way to write `C c("Hello", "to", "you");` `A* a = &c;` just for the B class?

Comment: @Nilzone-: I don't know what "just for the B class" means. If you only want an instance of class `B`, and don't need a full `C`, then just write `B b("Hello", "to")` in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    C c("Hello", "to", "you");

    A* a = &c;
    a->printInfo();  // "C class"
}
```

This, due to the keyword `virtual`, performs *virtual dispatch*, invoking the most-derived `printInfo`.

You can disable the virtual dispatch and invoke a specific function:

```
a->A::printInfo();   // "A class"
```

because `a` is a `A*` so the usual function call rules apply.

The left-out sheep here is `B::printInfo()`:

```
a->B::printInfo();  // error: 'B' is not a base of 'A'
```

`B::printInfo` is neither the most-derived overrider, nor a member of `A`. So, for this, you must make a promise to the compiler that `a` really points to a `C` (or, at least, a `B`):

```
static_cast<B*>(a)->B::printInfo();
                    // "B class"
```

Yuck.

Generally you should question your approach whenever this "need" arises, as it smells of bad design.

Comment: **Note:** In this answer, I have totally ignored the title of the question because "initialising" appears to have nothing to do with it.